# GoLand is stucking after installing plugin, displaying "Plugin to blame"

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

I installed some plugins for `jsonnet` format, after restarting the IDE, it stuck on the GoLand startup image.

I also opened the GoLand via terminal `/Applications/GoLand.app/Contents/MacOS/goland` and it shows some exceptions about having two plugins for a same file format:

```
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.ImplementationConflictException: Language with ID 'Jsonnet' is already registered: class com.jsonnetplugin.JsonnetLanguage
.
.
.
ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin to blame: Jsonnet Language Server version: 0.0.5
```

Is there any way to disable the plugins without the GoLand itself ( like config files or arguments ) so I can get the IDE running again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by disabling the plugin via config and the remove / re-enabling the proper plugin in the goland preferences itself, here are the steps:

1. Found the plugin identifier from the error logs, for my case it was `com.github.zzehring`
2. For disabling the plugin, there is a `disabled_plugins.txt` file on [IDE config path](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs#:%7E:text=macOS%3A,Application%20Support%2FJetBrains%2FIntelliJIdea2020.) ( if there is no file there, create it yourself ), put the plugin identifier from step 1 on a new line in this file. On macos it was located in `/Users/%my_user%/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/GoLand2021.2/disabled_plugins.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I went to the IDE plugin directory and removed jsonnet plugin files.

On my Mac:

/Users/ * /Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Webstorm*/plugins